# Finitely generated modules over complete ring is zero if

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over $\hat{R}$ which is $R$ completed with respect to a finitely generated ideal $I$. If $M \otimes \frac{R}{I^{n}} = 0$ for every $n$, is it true that $M = 0$? If not, is it true when $R$ is noetherian?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since $M\otimes R/I^n\simeq M/I^nM$ then $M=I^nM$ for every $n$. Now use that $M$ is an inverse limit of the system ${M/I^nM}$.

Comment: oh, if $M$ is an inverse limit of the system $M/I^{n}M$ then I am done, is this always true? What if $I$ is not finitely generated?

Comment: See https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/ComAlg/ComAlg4.pdf